# parametric equation of two equations of one line

Tags: parametric

Hi I would like to find the parametric equation of the line:

$\
\left\{ x+y=2 , 3x+y+z = 5 \right\}
$

I have tried to solve it by posing $z = t $ and it gives me

$\
\left\{ x=-(t-3)/2 , y = (t+1)/2, z =t \right\}
$

but I don't know if it is right.

Thank you.

Comment: One way to check, since all your equations are linear, is to plug in two (or more) values for $t$, and see whether each corresponding $(x,y,z)$ satisfies the original two equations. Since $t=0$ and $t=1$ give good points, I declare that your solution is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct.

You could also go like this
$$\begin{align}
x&=t\\
y&=2-t\\
z&=5-(2-t)-3t=3-2t
\end{align}$$

Comment: I found the point P0 (intersection between D1 and D2) but i need to find the parametric equation of a line L passing by P0 and that is perpendicular to the plan with D1 and D2. Do you have any idea how i cound do that? thank you :)

Comment: You also need to add $D_2$ equation. Also, you may need to ask a new question...